# From trello import TrelloClient stopped working

Tags: python, python-2.7, trello

I have a python 2.7 script that has been working fine for several years up until last week. The error I'm receiving is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Code Enforcement\ACD Admin Operations\GIS\Operations\User Acceptance Testing (UAT)\scripts\uat_email_script.py", line 13, in <module>
    from trello import TrelloClient
ImportError: cannot import name TrelloClient
```

How would one go about troubleshooting? I'm thinking it could be that trello changed the name `TrelloClient` to something else. I've tried the following different ways:

- `from trello import TrelloClient`
- `import trello`
- `from trello import*`

But none of them work. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a `trello.py` file in the same directory? You may be importing from it instead of the `trello` module you have installed somewhere else. Try `import trello` then `print(trello.__file__)` and see if it is what you expect.

Comment: I tried this and it returned `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.7\lib\site-packages\trello\__init__.pyc`. I think this is to be expected but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Well, that seems like a plausible path for the right code to be in, so I'm not sure what's gone on. Maybe somebody with more `trello` specific knowledge can help you better. I've updated the tags on the question (and fixed some minor formatting issues while I was editing anyway).